# SWRevealViewController rearViewRevealWidth

Tags: xcode, menu, width, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm tryng to change the width of menu view controller (rear), with code:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
revealController.rearViewRevealWidth = 300.0f;
```

but it work after 2 clicks of menu (menu opened 2 times).

Why it works after 2 clicks?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set the _rearViewRevealWidth property in SWRevealViewController.m method-

- (void)_initDefaultProperties

it will solve your problem.